# idf.py command not recognized on VScode

Tags: embedded, esp32, i2c, esp-idf, devkit

I have installed esp32 extension on my VScode and I was successfully able to flash my first program (blink) but when I write the command idf.py in my terminal it says The term 'idf.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.
any suggestions how could I solve this problem?
and another question is after flashing my program how could i stop it from running, i have tried the short cut command "Ctrl-]" but it doesnt work as well.

i have tried to check for the version by writing the command idf.py --version, but the same problem.

Comment: I have solved it successfully by killing the Terminal and open ESP-IDF Terminal :)